# In astrophysics, why is it OK to compare one observed galaxy field with the average of multiple simulated fields?

Tags: astrophysics, data-analysis

I am currently doing my BSc project on weak gravitational lensing. My supervisor gave me data from a field of galaxy clusters observed by the CFHTLenS.

She also gave me the data of 64 simulated fields of galaxy clusters, with varying cosmologies. (For example, I have 64 fields with $\sigma_8=0.7$ incorporated, 64 fields with $\sigma_8=0.9$ incorporated, and 64 fields of a fiducial cosmology.) The idea is to stack these 64 fields and then compare the results to the CFHT-observed field, to see if the parameters and statistics we use will provide good cosmological constraints.

To me, this seems strange. (By the way, I am asking this on here instead of my supervisor because answers on here usually come faster than email responses.)

The reason it seems strange is because I feel like it is analogous to the following experiment:

Imagine we want to see who is faster out of 20-year olds and 30-year olds. We take one 20-year old and measure their maximum speed. We take 64 30-year olds and average their speeds. Then compare the speed of the 20-year old with the average speed of the 64 30-year olds.

This would obviously not be OK.

Why is it OK to compare one observed field with the average of 64 simulated fields, rather than compare one observed field with 1 simulated field?

Comment: Why is the age of the 20-year old known in your analogy? In my understanding, the better analogy would be to compare the speed of a runner against the average speed of 20-, 40- and 60-year olds in order to get some constraint on the runner's age. Which would "obviously" be OK (though probably not very insightful, I have no idea how strongly speed correlates with age).

Comment: @ACuriousMind That makes a lot more sense now. I guess I was coming at it from the wrong angle. Would you mind wording this as an answer so that I can mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analogy is inaccurate - you're comparing the average data from your cosmologies with some $\sigma_8$ *in order to get constraints on the $\sigma_8$*, so the proper analogy would be that you *don't* know the age of the runner and compare their speed against the averages of three sets of 20-, 40- and 60-year old runners. You compare averages so that you don't find similarities between the reality and *one particular simulation*, but can be somewhat certain that the similarity (or discrepancy) to reality really is based in the differing $\sigma_8$.

Answer (score 1):

You're just doing statistics with an extremely small sample size (one).

Presumably, the statistics in question are defined (or at least approximated) by their mean and standard deviation. Taking average properties from simulations is one way to get at the underlying theoretical mean and standard deviation when calculating the true values would be prohibitive.

That said, the simulations should not be being averaged across different cosmologies. You compare how well each cosmology does in describing the real data to find which cosmology is closest.

Comment: OK, thanks. By the way, I'm not averaging over different cosmologies. I am averaging over one cosmology, then another cosmology, then the fiducial. Then comparing each to the observed data.